# how to design microservices with testing in mind

Tags: node.js, tdd, cote

I have one service that calls another service using `cote` library. I would like to know how to design the service so it is easily testable.

```
'use strict';

const logger = require('../../../helper/logger');
const Player = require('../../model/player_model/player_model');
const crypto = require('./../../../helper/crypto_helper');
const cote = require('cote');
let requester = new cote.Requester({name: 'findOnePlayer requester'});

/**
 * Creates new player in database
 * @param username / must be unique
 * @param password
 * @returns {Promise<Player>}
 */
module.exports.createPlayer = async (username, password) => {
  if (!(username && password && username.length && password.length)) {
    throw new Error('Both username and password are required');
  }


  const request = {type: 'findOnePlayer', username: username};
  const existingPlayer = await requester.send(request);

  if (existingPlayer) {
    throw new Error('Username is already taken');
  }


  const password_salt = crypto.genRandomString(16);
  /** Gives us salt of length 16 */
  const password_data = crypto.sha512(password, password_salt);

  const player = new Player({username: username, password_hash: password_data.password_hash, password_salt: password_data.salt});

  // save user
  return await player.save();
};
```

I would like to mock this method `const existingPlayer = await requester.send(request);` of requester object. But requester object is used as a contructor with `cote` library.

Any help, or direction in what I should be looking/investigating?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sinon.js' [Stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.4/stubs/) to stub the send() function of the requester.

I will demonstrate on a simple example. This file contains both the requester and responder and just returns "bar". It also exports the requester, as we need access to it in order to stub it.

```
const cote = require('cote');

// Responder
const timeService = new cote.Responder({ name: 'Time Service' });
timeService.on('test', async () => {
    return 'bar'
});

// Requester
const requester = new cote.Requester({ name: 'Client' });
async function test() {
    return requester.send({ type: 'test' })
}

module.exports = { test, requester } // Export the requester
```

The actual tests then have access to the requester and can use sinons `stub(obj, "method")` and `stub.returns('whatever')` functions:

```
const test = require('ava')
const sinon = require('sinon')
const foo = require('../')

test('test function should return bar when unstubbed and foo when stubbed', async t => {
    // Unstubbed call
    const returnValue = await foo.test()
    t.is(returnValue, 'bar')
    // Stub requester objects send function
    var stub = sinon.stub(foo.requester, "send");
    // Make it return whatever you like
    stub.returns('foo')
    // Test it
    const stubbedValue = await foo.test()
    t.is(stubbedValue, 'foo')
    // Remove the stub
    stub.restore();
    // Original unstubbed call
    const returnValue = await foo.test()
    t.is(returnValue, 'bar')
});
```

[Check out the docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.4/stubs/), as you might also want to use `stub.withArgs` or `stub.callsFake(fakeFunction)` to make it more flexible.